# OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument when opening a file

Tags: python, datetime

I'm trying to open a file with the name as the date and time formatted as dd-mm-yy hh:mm:ss.
Doing this:

```
from datetime import datetime
timestr = datetime.now().strftime("%d-%m-%y %H:%M:%S")
print(timestr)
f = open(timestr, "w+")
f.close()
```

always results in this error:

```
C:\Users\keona\Documents\Py>timetest.py
14-09-19 21:28:19
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\keona\Documents\Py\timetest.py", line 4, in <module>
    f = open(timestr, "w+")
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: '14-09-19 21:28:19'
```

However, the code works when I take off the seconds, for some reason??

```
from datetime import datetime
timestr = datetime.now().strftime("%d-%m-%y %H:%M")
print(timestr)
f = open(timestr, "w+")
f.close()
```

which results in a file named only this:

```
14-09-19 21
```

Any suggestions or ideas as to why this is happening?

Answer (score 2):

I'd say it might be because `:` is an invalid character in a filename in windows.

Try using `strftime("%d-%m-%y %H-%M-%S")`